# EF one-to-one relation not creates

Tags: entity-framework, one-to-one, ef-fluent-api

I'll try create one-to-one relation using EF and Fluent API.

First class:

```
public class Game
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Token { get; set; }
    public string Player { get; set; }
    public virtual Field Field { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Move> Moves { get; set; }
    public GameStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }
    public PlayerCode Winner { get; set; }

    public Game()
    {
        Status = GameStatus.NoteDone;
        StartTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        Winner = PlayerCode.None;
        Field = new Field {Game = this};
        Token = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

Secong class:

```
public class Field : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Game Game { get; set; }
    public string CellsString { get; set; }
}
```

And configure relations in context

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasRequired<Field>(g => g.Field)
        .WithRequiredDependent(f => f.Game);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

But after this relation in DB is not created. Tables look like this

[image: Created tables]

I try many variations of Fluent configuration, but no one works for me. Where i do mistake?

Comment: I've had the issue before where in a 1-1 required relationship, it uses the Primary Key of the table as the Foreign Key as well. Have you checked the actual constraints on the tables, not just the columns?

Comment: @Vlad274 thanks, I check my constraints and see that EF use PK as FK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a mapping for foreign key if you don't wish to add it as a property to your entity class.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
        .HasRequired(g => g.Field)
        .WithRequiredPrincipal(f => f.Game)
        .Map(m => m.MapKey("GameId"));
}
```

You probably meant WithRequiredPrincipal, not WithRequiredDependent since you probably want that foreign key to be in the Field table.